classification accuracy - image dataset
i have a dataset that contains images of n subjects. Each of the subject has a standard - normal image (file name contains 'Norm'). I want to build a classifier using Euclidean distance measuring the distance between the images and its corresponding 'normal' image and then measure the classification accuracy. I tried to measure with the standard image, but it was failing for me. If anyone can share some good pointers on how I should go about doing this measurement. Should I calculate the PCA and take the eigen vector and calculate the distance between the eigen vectors and each of the eigen values of the images?
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def extract_label_from_filename(filename):
    """
    Extract numeric label from filename.
    Example: 's11ll.png' -> 11
    """
    # Find all numbers in the filename
    nums = ''.join(char for char in filename if char.isdigit())
    if nums:
        return int(nums)
    else:
        raise ValueError("No numeric label found in filename")

def load_images_from_directory(data_directory):
    """
    Load images from a directory using PIL and convert them to numpy arrays.

    Args:
        data_directory (str): Path to the directory containing image files

    Returns:
        tuple: (images array, labels array)
    """
    images = []
    labels = []
    names = []
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(data_directory) if f.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))]

    for i in files:
        try:
            # Open image with PIL
            img_path = os.path.join(data_directory, i)
            with Image.open(img_path) as img:
                # Convert to RGB if image is in a different mode
                # if img.mode != 'RGB':
                #     img = img.convert('RGB')

                # Convert to numpy array
                img_array = np.array(img)

                # Extract label from filename
                try:
                    label = extract_label_from_filename(i)
                    images.append(img_array)
                    labels.append(label)
                    names.append(i)
                except ValueError:
                    print(f"Skipping file {i} due to invalid label format.")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing file {i}: {e}")

    if not images:
        raise ValueError("No valid images found in the directory")

    return np.array(images), np.array(labels), [name[:-4] for name in names]

# Usage
try:
    DATA_DIRECTORY = r"/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/extracted"  # Google drive
    images, labels, names = load_images_from_directory(DATA_DIRECTORY)

    print(f"Successfully loaded {len(images)} images")
    print(f"Image array shape: {images.shape}")
    print(f"Labels array shape: {labels.shape}")

    # Optional: Display first image to verify loading
    plt.imshow(images[0])
    plt.title(f"Label: {labels[0]}")
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    
# Creating train and test set (total 90 images - 15 test and 75 train)

x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []
a = np.zeros(16)
for i in range(len(images)):
    if(a[labels[i]] != 1):
        a[labels[i]] += 1
        x_test.append(images[i])
        y_test.append(labels[i])
    else:
        x_train.append(images[i])
        y_train.append(labels[i])
x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test)


 def create_column_vectors(images):
#     """Convert images to column vectors by stacking columns"""
     return np.array([img.flatten() for img in images])

 def get_normal_standards(x_train, y_train):
#     """Extract normal images as standards for each subject"""
     standards = {}
     for i, label in enumerate(y_train):
         if label not in standards:   Take the first image of each subject as standard
             standards[label] = x_train[i]
     return standards

 def classify_using_euclidean(test_vector, standards):
 #    """Classify an image using Euclidean distance to standard images"""
     min_distance = float('inf')
     predicted_label = None

     for label, standard in standards.items():
         distance = np.linalg.norm(test_vector - standard)
         if distance < min_distance:
             min_distance = distance
             predicted_label = label

     return predicted_label

#  Convert images to column vectors
 x_train_vectors = create_column_vectors(x_train)
 x_test_vectors = create_column_vectors(x_test)

 print(f"Shape of column vectors: {x_train_vectors.shape}")   Should be (n_samples, 77760)

 # Get standard (normal) images for each subject
 standard_images = get_normal_standards(x_train_vectors, y_train)

  #Classify test images
 y_pred = []
 for test_vector in x_test_vectors:
     predicted_label = classify_using_euclidean(test_vector, standard_images)
     y_pred.append(predicted_label)

  #Calculate accuracy
 accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
 print(f"\nClassification accuracy using Euclidean distance: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

 # Display confusion matrix
 cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
 print("\nConfusion Matrix:")
 print(cm)

  #Optional: Display some misclassified examples
 misclassified_indices = np.where(np.array(y_pred) != np.array(y_test))[0]
 if len(misclassified_indices) > 0:
     print(f"\nNumber of misclassified images: {len(misclassified_indices)}")

   #   Display first few misclassified images
     fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, min(20, len(misclassified_indices)), figsize=(12, 9))
     if len(misclassified_indices) == 1:
         axes = [axes]

     for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
         if i < len(misclassified_indices):
             idx = misclassified_indices[i]
             ax.imshow(x_test[idx])
             ax.set_title(f'True: {y_test[idx]}\nPred: {y_pred[idx]}')
             ax.axis('off')

     plt.tight_layout()
     plt.show()


